# Elections phragmen migration

Tags: storage, runtime-upgrade, migration, pallet-election-phragmen, election-phragmen

I am working on Substrate-based node upgrades for solo-chain.

I stick to Polkadot releases and during the upgrade from [polkadot-release-v0.8.27](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-release-v0.8.27) to [polkadot-v0.8.28](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.8.28) I found a [storage migration](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/7040/files#diff-3acd0cb73093b0cc01acfd0dc5646b31a309e57526f18d67d7e9d8708c325dbbR96). This migration has two parameters `old_voter_bond` and `old_candidacy_bond`.  I don’t understand what the migration does but according to the parameters names, it looks like I should pass values of [VotingBond](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1719/files#diff-db5840c3c03c740de25aed56b9257559c224a04619c079c94cddbb23f9a855a4L477) and [CandidacyBond](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1719/files#diff-db5840c3c03c740de25aed56b9257559c224a04619c079c94cddbb23f9a855a4R476). But in Polkadot repository this migration [called](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1719/files#diff-db5840c3c03c740de25aed56b9257559c224a04619c079c94cddbb23f9a855a4R958) with the arguments values 100 time lower.

The questions:

1. How to choose the correct arguments values to pass into the migration?
2. Can I switch from the [hardcoded value for VotingBondFactor](https://github.com/Cerebellum-Network/pos-network-node/pull/124/files#diff-67684005af418e25ff88c2ae5b520f0c040371f1d817e03a3652e76b9485224aR590) to [deposit(X, Y)](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/pull/1719/files#diff-db5840c3c03c740de25aed56b9257559c224a04619c079c94cddbb23f9a855a4R480) in later versions?